# How to cite a subsection of a book for IEEE

Tags: citations, citation-style, ieee

For example, we use pp. 4-7 for pages from 4 to 7 and ch. 2 for chapter 2, but how should we cite a subsection of a book when a chapter is divided into multiple subsections, e.g. 2.1, 2.2, ... in a way that's compatible with IEEE writing style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how should we cite a subsection of a book when a chapter is divided into multiple subsections, e.g. 2.1, 2.2, ...

Rather than citing the entire book, e.g., [1], you can cite a particular subsection, e.g., [§2.1, 1], [§2.2, 1], ..., meaning section 2.1, 2.1, ... of [1]. With Latex, you can use `\cite[\S2.1]{X}`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to see if there are special characters for subsections like ch. is for chapter or pp. is for pages or p. for page, etc.

Comment: @FriendlyFella I've given that symbol: §.

Answer (score -1):

Going by this [description of the IEEE citation style](https://pitt.libguides.com/citationhelp/ieee), you would just cite the page range, like this:

> Chapter in book
>
> [2] L. Stein, “Random patterns,” in Computers and You, J. S. Brake, Ed. New York: Wiley, 1994, pp. 55-70.

It doesn't seem to be necessary to give the exact chapter/section number.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, since this is what the citation style guide says you should do.

Comment: Would someone explain why this answer is downvoted? I accepted the other answer, because it suggests using "§" for sections and that is concisely what I was looking for, but I don't see why this answer would be wrong.